# Why we do not consider all the planes possible in a crystal for the derivation of Bragg's law?

Tags: optics, braggs-law

In the derivation of Bragg's law, I've seen that a particular set of planes is considered which are parallel to each other. But in a real crystal, many planes of different angles are possible. So, while deriving Bragg's law, shouldn't we consider the intensity at the detector to be the sum of reflections from all the planes, expressed as some sort of an integral over the angle $\theta$ that the planes make with the incident ray? Also, shouldn't we consider all the parallel planes, as opposed to the two adjacent planes near the surface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laue's theory of diffraction takes the approach you suggest. It does not consider any planes actually. It just integrate the contributions from all differential volumes of the crystal, for a given position of the detector. The condition for maxima obtained by this approach is equivalent to Bragg condition. So Bragg law diagram, with planes and Ray paths provides the  right condition even if it is not rigurously justified. It's not an unique case.  See Bohr's model predicting the location of spectral lines for
 hydrogen.

Comment: I'll surely study Laue's theory one day in the future. By the way, I wonder why did the Bragg father and son duo get the Nobel prize with a 'non-rigorous' derivation although the Laue equations which were more general and rigorous had been published one year before.

Comment: I think that they got it for their experimental work. Bragg was the first to actually do x-ray diffraction, confirming the periodic structure of crystals.And Laue got his Nobel before the Braggs.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know which derivation of Bragg's Law that you're looking at, as there are several ways of deriving the Bragg Scattering Condition. However, most derivations use the example of two crystallographic planes so that a *proportion* may be shown using the geometry of right triangles.

More specifically, note that the distance between planes (d) is an arbitrary constant, and the difference that the two rays of light you're examining have to travel is always directly proportional to it.